# Which of these CSS horizontal slider different implementations is better?

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I'm trying to figure out what way is better (I'm talking about CSS part) to create a horizontal content slider. Of course it's better to use jQuery UI or any other content slider, so it's just my curiosity how to implement content slider better. You can see my several solutions below.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">a</div>
            <div class="item">b</div>
            <div class="item">c</div>
            <div class="item">d</div>
            <div class="item">e</div>
            <div class="item">f</div>
            <div class="item">g</div>
            <div class="item">h</div>
            <div class="item">i</div>
            <div class="item">j</div>
        </div>
</div>
   <div class="slider"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.items').css('left', -ui.value * 4);
    }
});
```

});

CSS, first variant:

```
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px black solid;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .items {
        position: absolute; /*here is the difference*/
        width: 2000px;
    }
    .item {
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 160px;
    }
```

CSS, second variant:

```
        .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px black solid;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .items {
        position: inherit;
        width: 2000px;
    }
    .item {
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 160px;
    }
```

The question is what is better to use: relative + inherit or relative + absolute?

==And one more very similar implementation:==

HTML:

```
<div class="scrollableContainer">
<div class="content">
    <div class="scrollableContent">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.console').text(ui.value);
        $('.scrollableContent').css('margin-left', -ui.value * 4);
    }
});
```

});

CSS:

```
.scrollableContainer {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
}
.scrollableContainer .content {
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollableContainer .scrollableContent {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
}
.scrollableContainer .scrollableContent .item {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.scrollableContainer .slider {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* overridings for jquery UI styles: */
.scrollableContainer .slider .ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all {
    border: 4px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollableContainer .slider.ui-slider.ui-slider-horizontal.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Here I don't use any relative\absolute properties but I'm trying to move left-margin instead of left property. 
So the question is what solution is better?

=========================== 
Fiddles: 
[First variant's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9pdh/1/) 
[Second variant's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9pdh/6/) 
I can't post more then 3 link so the third variant's fiddle is here: http:_//jsfiddle.net/TGEQf/

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use transforms instead of animating left / right (if you're using transitions to change slides). Transforms can easily be hardware accelerated and, unlike `left` and `top` properties, changing them doesn't cause a reflow and can entirely be done in the GPU, even without repainting, so they have better performance.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you about transforms, but I'm talking only about this examples (position, left and margin properties).